# Error when concat two RNN cell with tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'c'
```

when trying to execute this function

```
def _add_encoder(self, encoder_inputs, seq_len):
with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
  cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim.value, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=False)
  cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim.value, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=False)
  (encoder_outputs, (fw_st, bw_st)) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw, encoder_inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seq_len, swap_memory=True)
  encoder_outputs = tf.concat(axis=2, values=encoder_outputs) # concatenate the forwards and backwards states
return encoder_outputs, fw_st, bw_st
  # Apply linear layer
  old_c = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[fw_st.c, bw_st.c]) # Concatenation of fw and bw cell
```

I am using python 3.6 , tensorflow 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short version:**

Remove `, state_is_tuple=False`

**Longer version:**

According to tensorflow document of [LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell),

> state_is_tuple:
>
> If True, accepted and returned states are **2-tuples of the c_state and m_state**.
>
> If False, they are **concatenated** along the column axis. 
>   This latter behavior will soon be **deprecated**.

And [LSTMStateTuple](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMStateTuple)

> Stores two elements: (c, h), in that order. Where c is the hidden state and h is the output.
>
> **Only used** when **state_is_tuple**=True.

So I suggest change

```
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim.value, initializer=self.rand_unif_init, state_is_tuple=False)
```

to

```
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self._hps.hidden_dim.value, initializer=self.rand_unif_init)
```